how to log request id in django middleware?
I write some code as below,but it raise an exception
here is request_id_middleware.py
import uuid

from django.middleware.common import CommonMiddleware
from taiji.logger import logger

class RequestIDMiddleware(CommonMiddleware):
    # pass
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['request_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        logger.info(f"start request id: {request.META['request_id']}")
        return request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.META.get('request_id') is None:
            response.headers['X-REQUEST-ID'] = request.META['request_id']
            logger.info(f"finish request id: {response.headers['X-REQUEST-ID']}")
        return response

logger.py
import logging


def set_logger(name):
    logger=logging.getLogger(name)
    handler=logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fmt=logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(fmt)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

logger=set_logger('gg')

views
def index(request: HttpRequest):
    logger.info("hello world")
    return JsonResponse("hello world")

but it tell me
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\miniconda\envs\py312\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\miniconda\envs\py312\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\miniconda\envs\py312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\miniconda\envs\py312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 141, in get_response
    response._resource_closers.append(request.close)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '_resource_closers'
[20/Apr/2024 22:32:59] "GET /index/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59

is it right way to implement a middleware?
why it call a WSGIRequest error? it should be a respone-like object error
Any help will be appreciate

Does it keep falling if you remove return request line from process_request definition? This may have something to do with middleware short-circuiting, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/middleware/

@STerliakov I found process_request and  process_response just fit for old deprecated middleware class, the my self-define middleware just need __call__ and __init__ as django doc said,but it still can't resolve the problem passing request id to logger

So you don't have this error any more, but are stuck passing a request ID? What's your deployment scenario? I mean, I do that with a logging.Filter that just uses a global variable on AWS Lambda, but doing the same in multi-threaded context is less trivial. You can find a similar implementation for single-threaded context in awslambdaric (permalink to the relevant snippet), your middleware would just set that global variable.

If you have a multi-threaded deployment scenario, I'd probably go with a threading.local variable and read it in the filter.

@STerliakov 斯特利亚科夫 I use gunicorn or uwsgi

@STerliakov I'm considering that using nginx's request id function,that could be more simple?

I'm not sure what your problem is. What is wrong with threading.local variable set in middleware? There's even a package doing that for you...

@STerliakov Yes,for make thing simple, I decide to refer that repo code to write my middleware

After reading Django middleware docs and this repo, I wrote a simple code like this.
from Application import local
import uuid

class UserAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        local.request_id = uuid.uuid1()
        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response



in Application.init.py

try:
    from asgiref.local import Local
except ImportError:
    from threading import local as Local


local = Local()


in request_filter.py
import logging

from Application import local

class RequestIDFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record) -> bool:
        record.request_id = getattr(local, "request_id", None)
        return True

besides,you just need config your django log config,add request_id and filter field to your config like that repo I mention in the begin, it work well for me
